# Fade effect on Slick's carousel edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Ken Wheeler's plugin, [Slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and as you can see in the image below, when a slide is sliding at the edge, it looks like it's being cut off. I'm thinking of a "fading edge", in which when a slide slides at the edge, it has a "softer" effect. Instead of this abrupt slide disappearance, a gradual (just like a fade effect) one. Is there any way to do it?

[image]

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  speed: 2000,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='carousel'>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kkVWQR4.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRWm3lB.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/2f2pUHi.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7TSiIkS.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXxnAnC.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get pretty close with `background: linear-gradient();` with `:before` + `:after` pseudo elements, but the link won't be clickable for any area gets covered. Just update the `width` and `rgba()` colors as needed.

**UPDATE:**

In order to make the links to be clickable even when they get covered, you can simply add `pointer-events: none;` to the pseudo element.

```
.carousel:before,
.carousel:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none; /*makes the linkes behind clickable.*/
}
.carousel:before {
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.carousel:after {
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwveLp8n/)**

Answer (score -1):

you need a .png image that has a fading mimic so transparency goes from 0 to 70%

then inside the container add the img twice second img should be flipped horizontal

css

```
.container img {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
/* selects the first img */
.container .img1 {
float: left;
left: 0;
}
/* selects the second img */
.container .img2 {
float: right;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: but this would still make the effect in image. What I mean is to have a fade in the edge (like a fade gradient).

Comment: this is custom coding but you're lucky i'm in a good mood. just find a png or create one and use this css.

Comment: thank for your attention, but it's showing a line in the middle only.

Comment: send me jsfiddle i'll look at it and fork it

Comment: i don't see no png you put inside the container. give it a class name and change .container img to .container .classnameoftheimage

Comment: thank you for your attention, but Pangloss solved already above.